# How to change URL (location) in Cordova ChildBrowser plugin?

Tags: ios, cordova, childbrowser

My application should change page displayed in ChildBrowser plugin based on incoming notification. 
Everything works fine, but I can't figure how to programmatically change location in ChildBrowser – e.g. something like `window.plugins.childBrowser.setURL(newURL)`.

Trying to call `openWebPage()` for the second time ends with exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <MainViewController: 0x2102ac20>.'
```

Trying to use `window.location = newURL` opens Safari with specified URL.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this by using Angular.js

Comment: Well. It's not fixed, but workarounded. We do not open specific URL but load another HTML in current view.